# Why did a monitor upgrade cause 1 game's content to not fit entirely on the screen?

Tags: display, upgrade

I just went from a 27 inch flat screen (4k, 60Hz) to a 35 inch curved screen (3440x1440, 200Hz) and now 1 of the games I play regularly will not load in "Full Screen" (defaults to "Windowed" mode) and more than half of what I used to be able to see is not on the screen. It kind of looks like I need a scroll bar (not an onscreen option) to see the other content. I do not consider myself a "Superuser". Please excuse what might be a simple (stupid) question. Any info would be appreciated and Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that the aspect ratio is uncommon and the game does not know how to handle it correctly. The aspect ratio of your new screen is about 21:9 while a 4k display is typically about  17:9.  This 17:9 is much more common.

Comment: Davidgo - thank-you so much. I will look into the aspect ratio setting. Thanks again.